# How do you do pagination in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, pagination

I have read DiscoverMeteor, in the book they are doing pagination like this:

when you access `/posts/10`, router will do a `subscribe('posts', {sort: {updated: -1}, limits: 10})`, and server return 10 posts, then when you click `Load more`, router will request `/posts/20`, that is `subscribe('posts', {sort: {updated: -1}, limits: 20})`, and server return 20 posts, then you got a post list with 20 posts.

Suppose this, I have 4 posts, and to make it simple I will get 2 posts every time.

First I do a `/posts/2`, then I got 2 posts, and the post list looks like this:

```
|   Post List   |
|      post4    |
|      post3    |
|  load   more  |
```

then a new post is added, what happens when I `load more`?

**A.** because a new post is added, so before I `load more`, the list becomes:

```
   |   Post List   |
   |      post5    |
   |      post4    |
   |      post3    |
   |  load   more  |
```

then if I `load more`, the list becomes:

```
   |   Post List   |
   |      post5    |
   |      post4    |
   |      post3    |
   |      post2    |
   |      post1    |
   |  load   more  |
```

**B.** before I `load more`, the list becomes:

```
   |   Post List   |
   |      post5    |
   |      post4    |
   |  load   more  |
```

then if I `load more`, the list becomes:

```
   |   Post List   |
   |      post5    |
   |      post4    |
   |      post3    |
   |      post2    |
   |  load   more  |
```

or other case? exactly What will happen?

How do you do pagination in meteor normally?

Comment: that's not pagination. For pagination (showing different sets of elements on separate pages) you can simply use a package.

Comment: The answer is B, but why don't you just try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the skip parameter in your subscription. Skip will move to the next items.

```
subscribe('posts', {sort: {updated: -1}, skip: 0 limits: 20}); //page 1


subscribe('posts', {sort: {updated: -1}, skip: 20 limits: 20}); //page 2
```

I'm not totally sure of the 'Meteor' way, but you can add a query string, and pass that along to the subscription